# Linux capability - non-root user child process to access files created by other users

Tags: linux, pam

I am running a process with root privileges which `fork` child process. Child process changes its `uid` and `gid` to user and group without root privileges. Would like to assign capability to this child process to access files created by other users.

Had tried different combination of assigning file and process capabilities using `setcap` command and `cap_set_flag` functions but nothing worked as expected. Tried using `cap_dac_override` and `cap_fowner` capabilities for this.

Also, gone through the [man pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) and other SO questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154427/fork-and-execve-to-inherit-non-rootparent-processs-capabilities), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956732/is-it-possible-to-configure-linux-capabilities-per-user) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17743062/changing-user-ids-for-assigning-additional-capabilities).

Now, I am more confused on how to set file and process capabilities to access files created by other users. Whats the correct way of doing this?

Comment: From my reading of the man page, you might need `CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH` along with `CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE`/`CAP_FOWNER`.

Comment: `@Andrew Henle` I had tried using `CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH`, but its not working.

Comment: I have code using `CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH` and reading a known other user's file does work. Looking for files by traversing filesystem does not.